# Show Whitespace in a textbox or richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, rendering, whitespace, gdi

There is an option in Visual Studio (since as far back as I can remember) that allows you to see "Whitespace" in your code. This is often seen in file differential viewers as well.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how this can be accomplished in VB.net (or any other way) so that i could use a similar type of display option in my software.

I have not yet tried to do this but my only first thoughts would be to override the "paint" of the textbox to actually add the little tab "arrows" and space "dots" manually via GDI, or create a texbox control from scratch. Seems to me there could be an easier way to do this.

Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Comment: Have you considered using [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex)?

Comment: Finding the Tabs and spaces are not an issue, can be done multiple ways. it's about the actually overriding of the SPACE and TAB character themselves to display the "synbol" for the user to see.

Comment: You can simply override the key events do get what you want with little effort.

Comment: I don't see how detecting the user entering a tab or space will change the rendered output, especially after multiple keystrokes and possible scrolling. I do not want to cahnge a tab/space from being a tab/space, just render the light gray arrow/dot in it's place. can you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the vbTab constant in the entirety of the document and replace them with a small arrow (`→`)(drawn with grey or whatev. you want)

Do the same for the space char but replace it with a grey dot (`·`)
if you want to change it back, replace `·` with spaces and replace the arrows (`→`) with tabs

after this is done set a boolean (`useSymbol`) to true  and use this boolean in the keydown event of the textbox to check whether you should print regular spaces/tabs or `·`/`→`

Comment: That is quite intelligent. Had not occured to me to actually change the character and font. I suppose I could use Webdings 3 "g" character for the arrow, and Webdings "=" as the dot with light font and I can totally avoid any graphical rendering overide. Also can use an extension method to parse it out when I need the "normal" text. Very nice, 2 thumbs up!

Comment: This works, but you lose the spacing that the tabs give you -- the arrow character is one character in width while the tabs can be anywhere from 1-8 characters in width. Any ideas?

Comment: @alldayremix maybe you could replace it with the arrow char + some leading & trailing special whitespace chars, anything different from space, so that it wont be replaced to dots when you switch

Comment: Okay, but then how do I find the displayed character width (e.g. 1 char, 3 chars, 8 chars) of a particular Tab character?

Comment: @alldayremix are you using richtexboxcontrol? if so richTextBox1.SelectionTabs may help you